# pod install also create 2. 3. files

Tags: git, cocoapods

I have an iOS project using CocoaPods. I have called pod install and I see untracked files added to the project: 2., 3.
It is always those files (i.e 2., 3.). Please see the attachment

[image]

The pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

# Pods for All

def general_pods
 pod "Branch", '~> 0.21.11'
 pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.28.0'
 pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.28.0'
 pod 'IGListKit', '~> 3.0'
 pod 'OpenTok', '2.12.0'

 pod 'Firebase/Storage'
 pod 'Firebase/Auth'
 pod 'Firebase/Database'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

 pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'

end

target 'MyApp' do
 general_pods
end
```

How do you stop it from happening?

Comment: Can you share the Podfile?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I have updated the question :)

Comment: @NDM-MobileDEV Please post the code, not an image of the code, which is not search friendly.  On top of the fact that it doesn't allow easy debugging.

Comment: @Daedalus Done, you are right

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce. Likely the result of something else specific to your environment.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I'll keep searching